# Using .each() and setTimeout works for first level of animation, but not second

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to make an animation where you click on the only div on the page, and it sequentially shows its sibling divs. There's some animation there, including an arrow that extends out a little when its parent div fades in--or, at least, that's what it's supposed to do.

The divs with the text work as expected. However, the second arrow completes its animation before the entire parent div has faded in. I've been working with setTimeout to try and delay the second animation until the first animation is complete per div, but it's not working the way I want it to.

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="learning-objs">
<div id="objs-button">
        <h3>Objective</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden lo-item">
        <div class="arrow">
            <div class="rectangle"></div>
            <div class="arrow-head"></div>
        </div>
        <ul id="lo-objective">
            <li class="lo-sub alpha">
                <h3>Objective</h3>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden lo-item">
        <div class="arrow">
            <div class="rectangle"></div>
            <div class="arrow-head"></div>
        </div>
        <ul id="lo-content">
            <li class="lo-sub alpha">
                <h3>Content</h3>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden lo-item">
        <ul id="lo-outcome">
            <li class="lo-sub alpha">
                <h3>Outcome</h3>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
#learning-objs {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
#objs-button {
    padding:0.5em 0;
    margin: 1em 0 0 3.5em;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
}
.objs-button-hover {
    background:#558448 !important;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#learning-objs .lo-item {
    width:12em;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    padding:0 1em;
}
#learning-objs .lo-item > ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
}
#learning-objs li.lo-sub.alpha {
    margin:0 auto;
padding:0.5em 0;
}
#learning-objs li.lo-sub.alpha, #objs-button {
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background:#88B77B;
    height:4em;
    width:10em;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
.arrow {
    margin: 1em 0 0 12em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.arrow-head {
    border-right:10px solid black;
    border-bottom:10px solid black;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin:25px 0 0 18px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
.rectangle {
    width:35px;
    height:10px;
    background:#000;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
    margin: 33px 0 0 0;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#objs-button').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('objs-button-hover');
});
$('#objs-button').click(function() {
    $('#objs-button').fadeOut(3000).removeClass('objs-button-hover').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $('.lo-item').each(function(i) {
        var objectiveItem = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(fadeInDiv) {
            objectiveItem.delay(fadeInDiv * 3000).fadeIn(1000);
            setTimeout(function(showArrow) {
                $('.rectangle').delay(showArrow * 3000).animate({
                    width: '45px'
                }, 600);
                $('.arrow-head').delay(showArrow * 8000).animate({
                    marginLeft: '28px'
                }, 600);
            }, 1000 * i);
        }, 500 * i);
    });
});
});
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/captainkayls/jjv6kev4/).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Functions in setTimeout dont receive any arguments. fadeInDiv and showArrow is wrong, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `setTimeout` is not the way.
Try this JavaScript. Is it that you wnat?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#objs-button').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('objs-button-hover');
    });
  $('#objs-button').click(function() {
    $('#objs-button').fadeOut(3000).removeClass('objs-button-hover').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $('.lo-item').each(function(i) {

      //I change only above
      var divLoItem = $(this);
      divLoItem.delay(1000 * i).fadeIn(1000);
      $('.rectangle', divLoItem).delay(1300 * i).animate({width: '45px'}, 600);
      $('.arrow-head', divLoItem).delay(1600 * i).animate({marginLeft:'28px'}, 600 );

    });
  });
});
```

Works fine. I think.

Here the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gydhk62L/

Comment: It is! Just so I understand what's going on, it was less a matter of timing and more a matter of how and with what I was applying the delay?

Comment: Yes. .each(function(index, obj) {}) function passing two arguments, the first being the counter (index). Is with him that we have to work to set the time of the animation.